$\|T^*T\|=\|T\| \cdot \|T^*\|$
Suppose we have a linear operator T between hilbert spaces and its adjoint T*. We know that $\|T^*T\| \leq \|T\|\cdot \|T^*\|$. Under which hypotheses can we conclude $\|T^*T\|=\|T\| \cdot \|T^*\|$? I came up with this question while I was solving an excercise where I was asked to find $\|T\|$ knowing that $T: L^2(-1,1)\to L^2(-1,1)$ is such that $Tf=H(x)\int_{-x}^{x}f(y)dy$ where $H(x)$ is the step function. The solution of the exercise is $\|T\|^2=\frac 8{\pi^2}$ which is the maximum of the eigenvalues of $\|T^*T\|$ (I understand that $T^*T$ is also compact so its norm is the max of the eigenvalues but I still don't get why he got the equality in this case).

For operators between Hilbert spaces, $|T^\ast T| = |T||T^\ast| = |T|^2$ is always true.

Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see meta

This question is a duplicate of Proving $||A||=||A^{}||=||AA^{}||^{1/2}$ and many others

Is this $T$ meant to be an operator between hilbert spaces? Or "only" betwee banach spaces?

Afaik the adjoint T* is defined only in Hilbert spaces?

It's always true. As you say, you always have $\|T^*T\|\leq\|T\|\cdot \|T^*\|$. You also have, for any $x\in H$,
$$
\|Tx\|^2=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle\leq \|T^*T\|\cdot \|x\|^2. 
$$
So you have $\|T\|^2\leq\|T^*T\|$. Thus
$$
\|T\|^2\leq\|T^*T\|\leq\|T\|\cdot \|T^*\|. 
$$
When $T\ne0$, you get $\|T\|\leq\|T^*\|$ (which is also true for $T=0$). As this can be done for $T^*$, you also have $\|T^*\|\leq\|T\|$ and so $\|T^*\|=\|T\|$. Now the two inequalities above become
$$
\|T\|^2\leq\|T^*T\|\leq\|T\|\cdot \|T^*\|=\|T\|^2, 
$$
giving you the equality $\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2$.

Better link to one of the many similar questions than post a duplicate answer.

Oh right I didn’t think of that thank you so much!
